# Reed-Solomon Decoding

Tags: error-correction

I've got a sequence of 28 bytes, which are supposedly encoded with a Reed-Solomon (28, 24, 5) code. The RS code uses 8-bit symbols and operates in GF(2<sup>8</sup>). The field generator polynomial is x<sup>8</sup>+x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>+1. I'm looking for a simple way to decode this sequence, so I can tell if this sequence has errors.

I've tried the Python [ReedSolomon module](http://hathawaymix.org/Software/ReedSolomon), but I'm not even sure how to configure the codec properly for my RS code (e.g. what's the *first consecutive root of the field generator polynomial*, what's the *primitive element*). I also had a look at [Schifra](http://www.schifra.com/), but I couldn't even compile it on my Mac.

I don't care too much about the platform (e.g. Python, C, Scilab) as long as it is free.

Comment: That Python module may not be correct because if you look on the web page, and follow the link to Phil Karn's page, the library that it is based on had a bugfix in 2007 but the Python module dates from 2005.

Comment: A bit late here, but the primitive element would be `x+0` or hex 02. The first consecutive root of the generator polynomial would normally also be hex 02: (x-0x02)(x-0x04)(x-0x08)(x-0x10) , but it could be hex 01: (x-0x01)(x-0x02)(x-0x04)(x-0x08). For the unusual case of using a self-reciprocal generator polynomial, the first consecutive root would be (hex 02)^126 (raised to the 126 power): (x-0x66)(x-0xcc)(x-0x85)(x-0x17) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I successfully built an embedded data comms project that used Reed Solomon error correction a few years ago. I just had a look at it to refresh my memory, and I found that I used a fairly lightweight, GPL licenced, C language subsystem published by a well known guy named Phil Karn to do the encoding and decoding. It's only a few hundred lines of code, but it's pretty intense stuff. However I found I didn't need to understand the math to use the code.

Googling Phil Karn Reed Solomon got me [this document](http://www.piclist.com/tecHREF/method/error/rs-gp-pk-uoh-199609/index.htm).

Which looks like a decent place to start. Hope this helps.

Comment: Understanding the math is easy compared to reading that code.  Lots of people have used it so I'm fairly certain it works, and if it solves your problem go for it.  If you think you need to change any of the code, you should probably write your own RS library.  It's the only way you'd get the education you need to have a prayer of understanding Karn's terse C code well enough to alter it.

Comment: Khan's code is very buggy. Correcting erasures doesn't always work, furthermore, his use of macros to "inline" certain computations is useless with today's optimizers. In short its a nice library to look at, but its not something I'd use in production.

Comment: Both I and the OP seem to get a regular stream of -1 reactions. A little puzzling to me, personally I would never -1 a genuine question or a genuine attempt to be helpful. Tough crowd.

Comment: This seems to be a broken link.